# Repeat the columns using data-sly-repeat based on the number entered in the cq dialog. Columns are not repeating

Tags: aem

I want to repeat the parsys in the columns based on the number of columns added in cq dialog. I can only get one column and the numbers of columns as entered

```
    <div class="items">
       <div data-sly-repeat="${grid.cols}" class="col col-lg-4 col-md-2 pt-2 pb-2">
          <div data-sly-resource="${'content-{0}' @ format=[colList.index], resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
        </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

carousel.js:

"use strict";
use(function() {

```
var properties = granite.properties,
    colCount = properties.numberofcolumns ? properties.numberofcolumns : 3,
    cols = '';

return {
    "cols"     : colCount
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

`data-sly-repeat` expects a list, not a number. You're only returning the number of columns. If you return an n-element list, `data-sly-repeat` will render an element for each item in the list.

It's a bit of a hack but in your `carousel.js`, you'd have to return an array with a list of values. The primary use case of `data-sly-repeat` (and `data-sly-list`) is to iterate over the elements of a collection returned by the underlying Java/JS code and output the properties of each item in the list. In your case, the only difference between the repeated `div` elements is the index.

```
use(function() {

    var properties = granite.properties,
        colCount = properties.numberofcolumns ? properties.numberofcolumns : 3;
    var resultList = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < colCount ; i++) {
        resultList.push(i);
    }

    return {
        "cols" : resultList // data-sly-repeat expects a collection
    };
});
```

On a more general note, it seems what you're aiming to do is to include a bunch of paragraph systems by name to achieve some sort of column layout. Before attempting this, I would consider using the OOTB [Layout Container](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/authoring/siteandpage/responsive-layout.html?lang=en) component, which can be resized in Edit mode to fit any number of columns without any new development.

Comment: Can you help me doing that as i am trying for long time and not getting the results

Comment: @Akshatha I've explained a little further, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to create the columns based on the number.  But unable to add different parsys to each columns. below is the code used

<div data-sly-repeat="${grid.cols}" class="col col-lg-4 col-md-2 pt-2 pb-2">
          <div data-sly-resource="${'content-{0}' @ format=[colList.index], resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
        </div>

Comment: @Akshatha in the snippet you posted in the comment you refer to `colList`, which doesn't appear to be defined anywhere. In a `data-sly-repeat`, [HTL will implicitly create a `itemList` variable](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#227-repeat) that allows you to access the index, among other things. If you want it to be named  `colList`, you need to name the variable `data-sly-resource.col=${grid.cols}`. Or you can just used the implicit `itemList`.